# What is the equivalent of python's faiss.normalize_L2() in C++?

Tags: c++, face-recognition, cosine-similarity, faiss

I want to perfom similarity search using FAISS for 100k facial embeddings in C++.
For the distance calculator I would like to use cosine similarity. For this purpose, I choose  `faiss::IndexFlatIP` .But according to the documentation we need to normalize the vector prior to adding it to the index. The documentation suggested the following code in python:

```
index = faiss.IndexFlatIP(dimensions)
faiss.normalize_L2(embeddings)
```

But as I would like to implement the same thing in C++, I noticed I couldnot find any functions in C++ that is similar to the one in python `faiss.normalize_L2()`.
Can anyone help?
Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build and use the C++ interface of `Faiss` library (see [this](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/blob/main/INSTALL.md#step-4-installing-the-c-library-and-headers-optional)).

If you just want L2 normalization of a vector in C++:

```cpp
std::vector<float> data;

float sum = 0;
for (auto item : data) sum += item * item;

float norm = std::sqrt(sum);
for (auto &item : data) item /= norm;
```